Was there an economic reason for Protestants' iconoclasm?
Europe underwent major economic upheavals during the creation of Protestantism (cf. E. Michael Jones, Barren Metal or Goy Guide to World History). Is this one reason why Protestants upheld iconoclasm? Was it a sense of necessity or utilitarianism (that having a minimally decorated church is better than having no church at all) that inspired or justified their iconoclasm?
In other words: Was there an economic reason for Protestants' iconoclasm?

You might want to look into the sociological concept of protestand work ethic. It mainly draws the opposite line: the protestant/calvinist emphasis on asceticism fed into the development of capitalism.

This question is so broad it might take a whole book to answer.

@BrianZ Aside from the fact the link leads to the transcription of a lecture, not a book, it does not in the least discuss economic reasons for iconoclasms, only their psychological impact. Quote: "A third motivation characterizes iconoclastic movements, such as that of the sixteenth century, where it is felt, ...that by damaging the symbols of a power...one somehow diminishes the power itself." Not  relevant.


Question:
Was there an economic reason for Protestants' iconoclasm?

Short Answer:
Yes Many.
Answer:
The Protestant Reformation, ignited by Martin Luther’s defiant act of nailing his Ninety-Five Theses to the church door in Wittenberg in 1517, is often remembered as a profound religious upheaval. Yet, beyond the theological debates and ecclesiastical reforms, there lies a significant economic narrative that underpinned the Protestant iconoclasm. The Protestant reformation was founded in protesting Catholic abuses of the time, many of which were economic in nature.  The destruction of religious images, the deprecation of religious relics and the redistribution of church wealth for the Protestants were driven by both spiritual fervor and calculated economic motives.  These included denying and repurposing the Catholic Church's revenue, reducing the burdon of the church on the people, giving the laity a larger say in their own finances, commercialization of religious goods previously denied to the laity, and retaining wealth among ordinary people.
One of the most immediate and visible economic impacts of Protestant iconoclasm was the confiscation of Catholic Church property. Monasteries, churches, and vast expanses of land were seized by Protestant rulers. This redistribution was not merely an act of rebellion but a strategic reallocation of resources. By seizing these properties, Protestant leaders could replenish state treasuries and reduce the Catholic Church’s influence. The newfound wealth allowed Protestant rulers to invest in state projects, thereby bolstering local economies and consolidating their own political power. This redistribution also weakened the Catholic Church’s economic base, shifting the balance of power significantly.
Protestant iconoclasm brought about a notable reduction in church-related expenditures. The Protestant rejection of religious images and iconography led to a significant decrease in the commissioning and maintenance of costly religious artifacts. Protestant worship services, in contrast to the elaborate Catholic rituals, were simpler and less expensive. This frugality extended to the broader economic practices of Protestant communities, reducing the financial burden on congregants and redirecting funds to more practical and immediate community needs.
By diminishing the economic power of the Catholic Church, Protestant iconoclasm inadvertently empowered the laity. The resources that were once controlled by the church became available to local communities and secular authorities. This shift enabled greater investment in local infrastructure and public projects, stimulating economic growth and development. Furthermore, the Protestant emphasis on reading the Bible in the vernacular spurred an increase in literacy and education. An educated populace was better equipped to contribute to economic productivity and innovation, further enhancing the economic vitality of Protestant regions.
The dismantling of Catholic practices such as pilgrimages and the veneration of relics had significant economic implications. These practices were lucrative for the Catholic Church, drawing pilgrims who spent money on various religious services and artifacts. Protestant reformers viewed these practices as superstitious and economically exploitative. By abolishing pilgrimages and the sale of indulgences, Protestants redirected wealth from the church to the secular economy. This shift reduced the church’s financial dominance and allowed for more equitable distribution of resources within the community.
Central to the economic critique of the Catholic Church by Protestant reformers was the practice of selling indulgences. This practice, which involved paying for the remission of sins, was seen as morally and economically corrupt. By rejecting indulgences, Protestant leaders sought to eliminate what they perceived as economic exploitation by the Catholic hierarchy. This rejection helped retain wealth within local communities and diminish the church’s economic stranglehold, fostering a more equitable economic environment.
The Protestant iconoclasm of the Reformation era was driven by the interplay of theological convictions and economic considerations. The destruction of religious images and the redistribution of church wealth were not merely acts of spiritual purification but also strategic economic decisions. By undermining the Catholic Church’s economic power, Protestant leaders facilitated a more equitable distribution of resources, empowered local economies, and fostered an environment conducive to economic growth and innovation. Understanding the economic dimensions of Protestant iconoclasm provides a more comprehensive view of the Reformation’s impact, highlighting how faith and finance were intertwined in the pursuit of reform and renewal.

? what does indulgences have to do with icons?

@MCW,   Protestant iconoclasm refers to the destruction or removal of religious images, icons, and other forms of visual art, relics deemed idolatrous by various Protestant reformers during the Reformation period in the 16th century.  Indulgences are also included as they were specifically targeted by Martin Luther in his Theses and likewise banned by the Reformation.

I'm well aware what the terms mean, but the relationship is an assertion that lacks either supporting evidence  or a framework that would explain.  I'm just not sure that this summary of the Protestant agenda is responsive to the question.

@MCW the question is about the protestant agenda.  Protestant iconoclasm is the Protestant agenda which came out of the reformation.

"Protestants redirected wealth from the church to the secular economy." – For the first two centuries after Luther, the majority of that wealth was directed into the war machine and the wholesale destruction of infrastructure that became the Thirty Years War. "The newfound wealth allowed Protestant rulers to invest in state projects, thereby bolstering local economies" – that effect is independent of the confession. Much of the wealth of the church expressed itself in owning territories, and those benefitted or suffered from the economic policies of their rulers just like the protestant ones.

Challenge: Work on the Münster of Ulm - a Protestant city - was stopped in 1543, after an iconoclasm in 1531. The work on the Cathedral of Cologne - the residence of the Catholic Archbishop-Elector - wound down after 1525. According to your thesis, Ulm should have benefitted more from that. Where is the evidence?

@ccprog,   ?  My thesis is that there were many motivations of the protestant iconoclasm beyond theological beliefs and scriptural reinterpretation including reaction against catholic practices, nationalism, social factors, politics, and yes economics.   Specifically dealing with economics there were many aspects of economics at play by the Protestant during the Reformation.    Not all benefited the laity but many did, some merely denied assets or revenue streams to the Catholic Church.
